# How to extract a raw list from a hashmap?

Tags: java

My friends and I are working on a Spring Activiti project, but I've stumbled upon a roadblock I can't seem to get through.

Here's the code sample from my friend's end:

```
DelegateExecution delEx = delegateTask.getExecution();
for(TransactionItem itemTransItem : transItem) {
    List forRequest = daoManager.getLaptopsForRequest(BigInteger.valueOf(itemTransItem.getAssetType().getId()), BigInteger.valueOf(approverId));
    forRequest.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.print(itemTransItem.getId());
    forReqeustMap.put(String.valueOf(itemTransItem.getId()), forRequest);
}
delEx.setVariable("forRequestMap", forReqeustMap);
```

The `for` loop sets the hashmap. Of note is that the value is a List, of (presumably) raw type.

The last line sets the hashmap in the delegate execution.

Now, here's the code on my end:

```
DelegateExecution delEx = delegateTask.getExecution();
HashMap<String,List> forReqeustMap = (HashMap<String, List>) delEx.getVariable("forRequestMap");

if (forReqeustMap.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Uh oh.");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Something else is wrong.");
    forReqeustMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("key: "+k+" value:"+v));
}

for (TransactionItem itemTransItem : transItem) {
    System.out.println(itemTransItem.getId());
    List forRequest = new List(forReqeustMap.get(String.valueOf(itemTransItem.getId())));
    if (forRequest.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Uh oh.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("What");
    }
}
```

Testing the hashmap `forRequestMap` for values yields true; the values are there.

The problem is extracting the list. The code I have simply doesn't work, yielding a null. I'm assuming it has something to do with either the way I'm trying to get the values, or the list itself - it won't even reach my `if-else` block without conking out.

I tried:

- adding a `<?>` to the List
- this: `List forRequest = forReqeustMap.get(itemTransItem.getId());`
- as well as adding `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`,

But none seems to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's an output log:
Output from the first batch of code:
`forRequest.forEach(System.out::println);`
`System.out.print(itemTransItem.getId());`

```
{asset_type_id=1, asset_id=1, id=1}
{asset_type_id=1, asset_id=2, id=2}
161
```

And here's the output from the 2nd batch (modified slightly from initial code):

`forReqeustMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("key: "+k+" value:"+v));`
`System.out.println(itemTransItem.getId());`

```
key: 161 value:[{asset_type_id=1, asset_id=1, id=1}, {asset_type_id=1, asset_id=2, id=2}]
161
```

EDIT: Update:

Changed this:

```
if (forRequest.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Uh oh.");
}
```

To this:

```
if (forRequest == null){
    System.out.println("Uh oh.");
}
```

And then I get an "Uh oh". Which means my forRequest is null. I then printed out the following:

```
System.out.println(forReqeustMap.get(itemTransItem.getId()));
```

Which gave me back a null, despite just printing out the k and v earlier. Now I'm really stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you're using a different `List`. AFAIK, `List` is an interface, and you cannot do `new List` unless you're creating an anonymous class, which doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: And you' be fine by declaring it as `List<Object>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I replaced it with `List<Object> forRequest = forReqeustMap.get(itemTransItem.getId());`. I'm still getting a null error by the if-else block.

Comment: Well, seems like `itemTransItem.getId` returns a different value.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I've added an output from the console. Seems everything is in order, but I'm not sure where it fails.